# Google Scripts - Retreive UrlFetchApp.fetch after javascript edited the page

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, inspect-element, view-source

I am trying to fetch a page (rotoql.com) using Google App Script's UrlFetchApp.fetch, but the rotoql.com is different in the 'Inspect Element' of a browser than it is in the 'View Source'. Unfortunately, UrlFetchApp.fetch grabs the 'View Source' version of rotoql.com as opposed to the 'Inspect Element' version.

How would I go about getting the version of a website that JavaScript had already edited (Or the 'Inspect Element' version) instead of the website's source code?

Comment: *UrlFetchApp.fetch grabs the 'View Source'* hmm, this is hard, the reason for the 'Inspect Element' part differs is that Inspect Element shows the DOM as it modified by javascript. not sure if google apps had something like `Selenium` to see those.. people already asked and no answer yet, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49486774/can-google-apps-script-be-used-for-browser-automation-form-filling-clicking-bu).. also try on [WebApps Stackexchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: I actually looked at Selenium...If I can't get this to work on google apps script I may just have to recede it on that platform instead. Thanks for the help!